# grant current user access to /dev/kvm

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm completely new to android development. After installing android studio with an empty project and adding a pixel device from AVD. On running it shows me the error

```
07/15 09:33:42: Launching 'app' on Pixel 3a API 28.
Error while waiting for device: Could not start AVD
```

I opened AVD manager where i can see

```
/dev/kvm device: permission denied
```

In troubleshooting options i can see
`Grant current user access to /dev/kvm`

I've already tried many tricks and i'm the member of kvm
after running following commands(found in answers on stack) in terminal i got the following output:

$ ls -al /dev/kvm:

```
crw-rw---- 1 root root 10, 232 Jul 15 09:19 /dev/kvm
```

$ grep kvm /etc/group:

```
kvm:x:1001:
```

sudo chown $devendra /dev/kvm: after entering password:

```
chown: missing operand after ‘/dev/kvm’
Try 'chown --help' for more information.
```

But after running the command :' $ sudo chown devendra /dev/kvm '
program runs but only for once. On re-run it again gives the same error:

```
07/15 09:33:42: Launching 'app' on Pixel 3a API 28.
Error while waiting for device: Could not start AVD
```

For every run of program i have to run the command ' $ sudo chown devendra /dev/kvm ' Why?

Now i don't understand where i'm wrong or what i'm missing. Please guide me.

Answer (score 5):

It's quite strange that group "root" have access to "/dev/kvm", in my case, it's group "kvm":

```
ls -l /dev/kvm
crw-rw---- 1 root kvm 10, 232 sept.   5 23:55 /dev/kvm
```

Adding current user to group "kvm" solved my problem:

```
usermod -a -G kvm yourUserName
reboot
```

Answer (score 3):

**Ubuntu**

Make sure KVM exists,

```
$ kvm-ok
```

Install, `sudo apt install cpu-checker` if required

Output should be,

```
INFO: /dev/kvm exists 
KVM acceleration can be used
```

then try,

```
$ sudo su
$ cd /dev/
$ chmod 777 -R kvm
```

Now start the emulator.

Answer (score 2):

**For Ubuntu:**

Add User by using
`sudo adduser $USER kvm`.

then restart your Laptop.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether you have properly installed kvm or not.Follow official link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation. (PS:This is for linux distributions)  Then once check with rebooting the system after installation this did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Update BIOS Setting

1. Power on the system and press[delete] key to enter BIOS [EZ Mode]
2. 2. Press the [F7] key to enter BIOS [Advance Mode] as below picture：(If press the [delete] key to enter [Advanced Mode] directly and then no need to press the [F7] key any)
3. Select the [Advanced] page and click [CPU Configuration] item
4. Select the [Intel(VMX) Virtualization Technology] item and set to [Enabled]
5. Press the [F10] key and click [OK],the system will auto reboot

[image]